# Creating custom keyboard shortcuts in eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse

I'm using the eclipse c++ IDE and I want to create a key board shortcut that basically does two steps:
1. Saves all files
2. Builds project

Is there any way to do this ?

Comment: why the downvote? I upvoted to neutralize the opposition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To save all files the shortcut is `CTRL+SHIFT+S`. You can modify it
   `Window->preference->General->Editors->Keys`
2. You can select `build automaticaly` in file menu `Project`.

Now when you save the files the project will build automatically.